# TCP SOCKET : Stream is sent/received twice in asynchronous operation

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm currently working on asynchronous TCP program but I'm having the following issue:

- -When the Server sends some stream , the Client first receives an empty buffer and then it receives the stream.
- -After the first stream sending,if I'm sending another stream the client's buffer contains the first stream sent and the current
  stream.
- -If I'm sending another stream, the buffer will contain the stream I sent before and the current one..and so on..

This is really annoying and I don't know where's the problem.
Here is my CLIENT Code:

```
Socket CLIENT;
byte[] _buffer;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Start();
}
void Start()
{
    CLIENT = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    CLIENT.BeginConnect(IPAddress.Parse("the IPaddress"), 1234, new AsyncCallback(ConnectionCallBack), null);
}
private void ConnectionCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
         CLIENT.EndConnect(ar);
         _buffer = new byte[CLIENT.ReceiveBufferSize];
         CLIENT.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), null);
    }
    catch (Exception Er)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("[[[[ERROR:1]]]]=>" + Er.Message);
    }

}
private void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        int lenght = CLIENT.EndReceive(ar);
        if (lenght == 0)  { return; }
        Array.Resize(ref _buffer, lenght);
        string stream = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(_buffer);
        Array.Resize(ref _buffer, CLIENT.ReceiveBufferSize);

        CLIENT.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), null);

    }
    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show("[[[[hoERROR:2]]]]=>" + ex.Message); }
}
```

Here is the server:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            try
            {
                Socket socket = (Socket)listW.SelectedItems[0].Tag; //contains the socket
                socket.BeginSend(_buffer,0,_buffer.Length,SocketFlags.None,new AsyncCallback(SendingCallBack),socket);
                ServerSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack),null);
            }
            catch (Exception er) { MessageBox.Show("[[[[ERROR:]]]]=>" + er.ToString()); }
        }
        private void SendingCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                _buffer = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tx1.Text);
                socket.BeginSend(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(FinalCallBack),socket);
            }
            catch (Exception er) { MessageBox.Show("[[[[ERROR:3]]]]=>" + er.ToString()); }
        }
        private void Final(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Socket client = ar.AsyncState as Socket;
            client.EndSend(ar);
        }
```

Comment: I have a project on github that might help you: https://github.com/Mellen/Networking-Samples

Comment: Thanks but I need to understand what is wrong in my code.where's the mistake

Comment: I deleted your newer question and undeleted this one because it's fairly disrespectful to delete a question that someone took the time to answer, just so that you can repost it to get more attention. Please don't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a few problems.  One seems to be the `stream` in `ReceiveCallback`.  You get a string from the buffer then do nothing with it.  Resizing your buffer down then resizing if back up to the original size seems like a waste.  Might was well make a copy of the data then call `GetString` and you can leave your buffer alone.

In your server, you call `BeginSend` to send _buffer, when that completes you call `BeginSend` again in `SendingCallback` with the binary representation of `tx1.Text` **but you don't call `EndSend`**, when that completes you call `EndSend` on the 2nd `BeginSend`; but still haven't called it for the 1st.

Comment: I don't get it , how I'm supposed to call end send for each sending because as I can see , in the server it is already done ? (if this is what you're saying.)

Comment: @leo In `SendingCallback` you need to call `EndSend` passing it `ar`, just like you did in `Final`.  I don't know what the consequences are from that missing `EndSend`--likely not good